# Is the Canon 75–300mm EF lens compatible with a EOS 400D?

Tags: lens, canon

I have a Canon EOS 400D. I am looking at the 75–300mm Canon EF lens.

Will this lens work for my camera?

Comment: You may also wish to consider reading one of the many answers on this site about the (complete lack of) merits of the 75-300, one of mine is [here](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/39252/11371).

Comment: Another question with similar answers re: the 75–300: [How does the Canon EF 75-300mm USM III compare to ...?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/30106/11924)